# Google Analytics API - How to group by ga:medium and ga:transactionId?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, enhanced-ecommerce

I am calling the Google Analytics API (w/ e-commerce) to get a simple set of data:

**Dimensions**

- `ga:medium`
- `ga:transactionId`

**Metrics**

- `ga:transactions`
  *This should in theory give me 0 or 1, since the data is broken down by `transactionId`*

What I'm assuming I will get is something like:

```
['organic','transaction_1000001','1']
['organic','transaction_1020001','1']
['organic','transaction_1000501','1']
['organic','transaction_1001001','1']
...
['email', 'transaction_1001001','1']
...
```

But instead, I don't get the `ga:transactionId` dimension. I only get results grouped by `ga:medium`:

```
['organic','1238']
['email','151']
...
```

I don't really care about the metric, it could be anything. What I need want is to get the medium with the transactionId.

So, is there a way to get a result set grouped by `ga:medium` and `ga:transactionId`? Why is the `ga:transactionId` dimension ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue. Hopefully this answer helps anyone facing this problem.

I was using the NodeJS api bindings. Turns out, the `dimensions` (and `metrics`) properties need to be strings. I was using an array.

The `dimensions` value needs to be specified like this:

```
ga:medium,ga:transactionId
```

So a simple `dimensions.join(',')` fixed it.